# Tagging lots of tests at once in ScalaTest

Tags: scala, scalatest

I know i can tag a test using the `taggedAs` method (I'm using `FlatSpec` right now) like this:

```
                         \/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/
it should "not deadlock" taggedAs SlowTest in {
  Par.run(Executors.newFixedThreadPool(2))(Par.parMap(List.range(1, 100000))(math.sqrt(_)))
}
```

But I'd like to know whether i can tag a lot of tests all at once

something like:

```
taggedAs (SlowTest) { // yes this doesn't work, I've tried it.
  //a bunch-o-tests
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can do this, as per the `FlatSpec`'s nature:

> We recommend `FlatSpec` as the default choice, because it is flat (unnested) like the XUnit tests familiar to most developers, but guides you into writing focused tests with descriptive, specification-style names.

If you use a different ScalaTest flavour which allows you to group tests, then I'm assuming you'll be able to tag them all at once, tagging the group. Haven't checked this though.